# How to organise tests for multiple versions of a feature

Tags: manual-testing, test-management

I have this scenario for using Jira and Zephyr:

I wrote a test against "Feature A" for release "Release 1". Now some of the functionality of "Feature A" was changed for "Release 2".
I want to be able to keep testing both versions of "Feature A" for each individual release.

As far as I understand Zephyr only allows one instance of a test case (at least in the former versions...). So if I would edit the test case for a future version of a feature I would also change the content of the existing test cycles.

How would you organise your test cases?

1. Clone and edit test case for each version of "Feature A" and add it to the individual release version?
2. Use the new test case versioning functionality of Z4J  I am not aware of?
3. ...?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From what they say on the official zephyr support site it is not possible. Proposed workaround is to clone the test cases, as you have suggested:

> For now only way is to clone test cases for version .In other way is to create only one testcase and add it to different cycles of different versions.This way you can use only one test case for multiple versions.

Here is the link to the thread on the support site: [zephyr suport](https://support.getzephyr.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/208925903-Recommended-workaround-for-versioning-of-test-cases-in-Zephyr-for-JIRA-)